# SSH tunnel always trying port 22

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, raspberry-pi, tunnel

I want create ssh tunnel between local machine and remote server, so I use this command on my local machine:

```
sudo ssh -R 443:localhost:443 SERVER_IP
```

Everything is working, I can connect to my local machine through remote server - using port 443.

Problem is, that sometimes it just doesnt work and I get a message:

```
connect to host SERVER_IP port 22: Connection refused
```

Strange is, that connection to port 22 is working on remote (I can connect there without problem at that exact moment), weird is just, that sometimes it is working and sometimes id does not. Do you have any idea why? Or do you know what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

`ssh` runs by default on port 22.  While your command is setting up a proxy to pass port 443 from one host to port 443 on a different host, the underlying `ssh` connection still runs on port 22.

`Connection refused` means that the target host `SERVER_IP` is not running an `sshd` daemon and/or is not listening to port 22.  You will need to figure out and fix whatever is wrong with the `SERVER_IP` machine.

Comment: Problem is, that i can connect using ssh to remote using port 22, I just cant create tunnel using port 443. Dont know why

Answer (score -1):

22 is the default port, the ssh client will connect to it until you specify an other port using -p, example:

```
ssh -R 12345:localhost:12345 SERVER_IP -p 443
```

The error you have is not about the tunnel but about the server's port.
You should check that the server is indeed started and listening on port 22 and there's no firewall in the way.

Comment: No, first port 443 means, that anyone can connect to remote port 443 and will be redirected from remote to lolcalhost on (second) port 443 
https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example  - section remote forwarding

Comment: if you don't specify -p ssh will connect to the port 22. You apparently want it to connect on the port 443, why not, but then you can't at the same time use it for the tunnel. If you did want to connect to 22 then it's just that the ssh server is not reachable for some reason